# Can you relieve the symptoms of sinusitis by creating a negative pressure using your lungs?

Tags: ears-nose-throat-ent, sinus, sinus-congestion, sinus-headache

There seems to be a lot of more or less effective home remedies for relieving the painful pressure buildup in your sinuses when suffering from cold-related sinusitis. They include things like massaging various points on your face, pressing your tongue at the roof of your mouth, using a neti pot to rinse your nasal passage, etc.

But one thing I haven't been able to find any information on, and which for me seems to be a simple solution (if it works) is to simply cover your nostrils and try to breath in, thereby creating a negative pressure which could potentially suck some mucus out of your sinuses, equalize the pressure and relieve the painful pressure-related symptoms.

Could this work, and would it be safe?

Comment: This is a hypothesis. To confirm it, you would need to do some sort of experiment. Everything else is just guessing.

Comment: The reason I'm asking is because I'm hoping someone else knows. Just because I haven't been able to find any research on it doesn't mean there is none.

Comment: If it works for you, it works for you. Why would anyone invest the time and money to do research?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In sinusitis, there may already be a negative pressure in the sinuses ([nih.gov](http://ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK459372)).

One problem is that in sinusitis the openings that connect the nasal cavity and sinuses are usually clogged, so the attempt to create a pressure difference might be quite hard.

I'm not aware of any published experiments on this topic, but as suggested in one comment: the one who tries it and it works for him/her will know better than anyone. Either a negative or positive pressure (Valsalva) might work. Trying to thin the mucus by using a neti pot or inhaling hot water vapor beforehand might help.

No medical advice here. Warning: exaggerated experimenting with creating different pressure in the nasal cavity may be potentially dangerous.